# Twilio PHP: How to get outgoing SMS message SID

Tags: php, sms, twilio, twilio-php

I use Twilio PHP API and try to record SID of outgoing SMS messages. How to get that info?

I don't have problem to send and recive SMS, that work fine but SID from outgoing messages I need to get messages directly from Twilio in another APP where I not save all message data in database.

```
$twilio = new Services_Twilio('SID','TOKEN');

    $message = $twilio->account->messages->sendMessage( 
        $_POST['From'], // twilio phone number
        $_POST['To'],   // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
        $_POST['Body']  // the sms body
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To get the [message SID](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message), all you need to do is read the value of `$message->sid;`.

So in your code you could do:

```
echo $message->sid;
```

If you wanna see all the variables returned by the request, you could do something like:

```
var_dump($message);
```

And this will give you information about all the variables returned.

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Twilio REST API](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/) to send messages, then you can fetch the Message SID like below:

```
$sms_sent = $client->messages->create(
    '+1xxxxxxxxxx',
    array(
        'from' => 'MESSAGING SERVICE SID',
        'body' => "XXXXXX XXXXXX",
        'statusCallback' => "http://myapplication_callback_url"
    )
);

$sms_sent = (array) $sms_sent;
$sms_sid = $sms_sent["\0*\0" . 'properties']['sid'];
```